# How to creating Paypal connected(seller onboarding before payment) account using API?

Tags: php, paypal

I want to create seller onboarding account before payment(connected account under master payal business account). For that we using below API to connect customer and create account.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/seller-onboarding/before-payment/

After creating seller account we want to process MOTO payment (Telephony payment) into that seller account. Therefore we need API username, password and signature to process payment using Paypal API and process MOTO payment to that account.

Can you please help us to achieve this kind of functionality using Paypal API's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Onboarding](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/seller-onboarding/) requires being an approved PayPal partner, so you'll have to contact PayPal about this. Unless you do hear back with an approval and further guidance, any attempt to use onboarding APIs in production will result in a `401 Unauthorized` response.

Username, Password, and Signature are used by the old legacy classic APIs. You should not be integrating with classic APIs, but rather the current PayPal REST APIs, such as v2/checkout/orders, which use a `clientid` and `secret`.  If you need a seller's credentials, the way to get them is to ask. They can obtain them via an App in the "Live" tab of https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications , and copy them to your interface. You should then try to obtain an access token to verify that the credentials are valid, and prompt the user to re-enter valid credentials if they are not.